# Identifying CheckStyle Errors via Maven CLI

Tags: checkstyle

I build my projects via **mvn** on the command line.

Whenever a checkStyle error occurs, I see this type of output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-
plugin:2.4:checkstyle (default) on project myProject-server: 
An error has occurred in Checkstyle report generation. 
There are 2 checkstyle errors. -> [Help 1]
```

How do I find out which code lines are causing these CheckStyle failures?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

CheckStyle saves reports to `target/checkstyle-result.xml` (for non-modular project). So you may find out this file and examine it.

Another case is to configure `maven-checkstyle-plugin` to show all such warnings/error to console:

```
<consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
```